# Get first cell of row and top cell of column

Tags: jquery

I have a big table (id=PersonValue) with a top th row of nummeric values and the first cell of every row is a name.
When I click a certain cell in the table I want to retrieve the name in the first cell of that row and the nummeric value in the top cell of that column.

I've found this script to retrieve the name and adjusted it accordingly but it doesn't give me the name.

```
$('#PersonValue').click(function(){
    var name = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:first').text();
    console.log('Name is '+ name); // returns 'Name is ' while something like 'Name is Niko' is expected

  //var number = ??
});
```

And I have no idea on how to get the top cell as you can see in the script.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a complete [working solution](http://jsfiddle.net/Czv8R/1/):

```
$('table').on('click', 'td', function() {
    var $this = $(this),
        name = $this.siblings(':first-child').text(),
        pos = $this.index() + 1,
        num = $this.parent().siblings().first().children(':nth-child('+pos+')').text();

    alert(num + ' & ' + name);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this block of code:

```
$('#PersonValue').click(function(){
    var name = $(this).siblings('tr').find('td:first-child').text();
    console.log('Name is '+ name); // returns 'Name is ' while something like 'Name is Niko' is expected

  //var number = ??
});
```

I used `siblings()` and added selector `:first-child`

Answer (score 0):

```
 $('#PersonValue tr').on("click","td",function() {

        var $td=$(this);
        var $tr=$td.parent();
        var tdindex=$td.prevAll().length;
        //or try $td.index();

        var name = $tr.find('td:first-child').text();
        var colheader =  $('#PersonValue').find("thead > th:nth-child("+tdindex+")").text(); 
 })
```

have not tested it, nor seen your html (th in thead ?) but you get the idea i hope.
edit : try the index method while delegating from table tr

edit : this prevall method to get the index sounds better actually